# iOS - scroll view with multi view: scroll, map view... like Expedia Hotels & Flights

Tags: ios, background, scrollview, multiview

Recently I used app Expedia Hotels & Flights and interested in view hotel's detail.

I'm wonder how to implement scroll like that. When you scroll one view, it effects to its sub-views.

Could you please give me some advice for this idea? Thanks.

p/s: you can see the demo at [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hu45DrvqrVg&feature=player_embedded). ( 2:00 -> 2:30). It is demo on Android but same on iPhone.

image link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fiCf.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I found some key word for this feature. You could use "Parallax Scrolling Effect". Then re-custom scrolling for mapping with your requirement.

In Expedia Hotels & Flights, I think they have 3 main view: 
Scrollview: control palrallax effect. 
Top View: view on top.
Main View: view which hold other view in main.